# Jquery: loop on child elements based on parent class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have my form structure as below :

1. Each required element as a parent class `is_required`
2. Child class has element specific class name like `checkbox_required` or `radio_required` etc

i want to loop on all  for elements inside `is_required` class and then based on sub class do the required validation. My problem is i am not able to select the child class:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="form-group is_required">
      <label>radio button</label><br>
      <div class="radio_required">
         <input type="radio" name="radio_button" value="1">1
         <input type="radio" name="radio_button" value="2">2
         <input type="radio" name="radio_button" value="3">3
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group is_required">
   <label>checkboxes</label><br>
   <div class="checkbox_required"> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="one">one
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="two">two 
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="three">three
   </div>
</div>
```

i am looping through all these elements as below

```
$(".is_required").each(function() {       
        var div = $(this)+" > div";// Not sure how will i get the div here need to get radio_required, checkboxe_required etc 
})
```

can someone advise me how can i achieve that

Comment: You could do `var ele = $("> div > *", this);`

Comment: Your attempt would be: `$(".is_required").each(function() {  var childitems = $(this).find(">div")`  but you could also do `$(".is_required > div")` and skip the first `.each`  - might be better to do `$(".is_required>.radio_required,.is_required>.checkbox_required")` to get those specifically.  However the validation will likely be different inside each so you'd need `if ($(this).is(".checkbox_required")...` so you might as well do them as separate checks: `$(".is_required>radio_required").each...` and `$(".is_required>checkbox_required").each...`

Comment: @freedomn-m  =$(this).find(">div") this works

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code

```js
    $(".is_required").each(function() {   
          var element = $(this);
          //Loop all children elements of current element
           $(element).children().each(function () {
            if($(this).hasClass("checkbox_required")){
                var checkboxElement = $(this);
                console.log($(checkboxElement).attr("class"));
            }
            else if($(this).hasClass("radio_required")){
                var radioElement = $(this);
                console.log($(radioElement).attr("class"));
            }
        });
    })
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="form-group is_required">
          <label>radio button</label><br>
          <div class="radio_required">
             <input type="radio" name="radio_button" value="1">1
             <input type="radio" name="radio_button" value="2">2
             <input type="radio" name="radio_button" value="3">3
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group is_required">
       <label>checkboxes</label><br>
       <div class="checkbox_required"> 
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="one">one
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="two">two 
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="three">three
       </div>
    </div>
```